# List of QVideoFrames from video file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get list of QVideoFrame in Qt from a video file (doesn't really matter what format). I've looked at http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qvideoframe.html to find some information about QVideoFrame, but I can't find any information on how to make QVideoFrames from video file.

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/multimedia-videowidget.html) is old, but it should be decent starting point.